# tkinter get input from entry

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to get an `Entry` field from a method but my approach just doesn't seem to work.

```
class labdo:
    def abdos(self):
        top = myGui.top = Toplevel()
        Label(top, text="Value").pack()
        self.koco = Entry(top)
        self.koco.pack(padx=5)
        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.bellos)
        b.pack(pady=5)
    def bellos(self):
        print (self.koko.get())
```

`command=self.bellos` works but I cant get the entry value to print in the `def bellos` method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error that you get telling you? It probably is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple spelling error: you typed `koko` instead of `koco` in `def bellos`.
Change

```
print (self.koko.get())
```

To

```
print (self.koco.get())
```

Comment: Thanks I had been expecting much worse